# swapping of columns in a data grid view

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, binding, dataset

i have a c# windows form application, in all tabs inside it, i have a data  grid view that display data of a punch machine(ID,IP,Port,Type,Description,Location)

there's no errors, but the problem is sometimes the ID is shown instead of the Description Field,knowing that the ID is hidden in the grid..

So what's the possible problem?

the grid view is filled from a data set through a binding source.
all the grid has the same binding source, all are the same,
and i load the data on the form load.

Comment: Please provide sample code to analyse it better...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that before.  I don't know what causes it.  It seems to happen only if you hide the first column.  I don't know if this is the right way to fix it but I moved the ID column away from the first column.  In my case, I put it at the end of the dataGridView and I didn't see this "bug" again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was in a combo box that are binded to the same binding source of the grid..i was filled the "Selected Value" field which is wrong..so simply remove the selected value from the combo box